# How can I specify 2 different values of same system property or VM Argument?

Tags: java, realm, kerberos, jvm-arguments, system-properties

I have a system property which I use in my Intellij's VM arguments section as

`-Djava.security.krb5.realm="EXAMPLE1.COM"`, I want to use another value for the `realm` name instead of `EXAMPLE1.COM` when I connect to another resource.

For example, my MongoDB sits in `EXAMPLE2.COM` and my Kafka sits in `EXAMPLE1.COM` and have same userAccount having access to both the different realms. How to connect to both of these by setting the same VM argument having 2 different values from my application code ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try calling method [setProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) ?

Comment: Isn’t this what a `krb5.conf` file is for?

Comment: Correct, but my krb5.conf already has the details for both the realm names. under `[realms]` but, my application only takes one vm argument for realm name & connects to one resource either mongo or kafka, unable to talk to both the realms.